# Javascript: Pagination

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

I have to get from and to indices of the records.

Ideas would be appreciated. For instance, if:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
records_per_page = 4
```

the page numbers would be 1,2,3,4,5 (last page having one record).

I need to get the indices based on the page numbers.

For Example I click Page 1, it should give me 0 and 3 so that I send this from and to indices to server and then it returns me values [1,2,3,4]

If I click Page 2, it should give me 4 and 7 so that server returns me values [5,6,7,8]

```
function(total, page_no){ 
 // Need to return the indices of the records
 return [from,to]
}
```

Comment: The first index is `(page_no - 1) * records_per_page`, the last index is `page_no * records_per_page - 1`.

Comment: @RAVIPATEL I guess the answer you mentioned gives the data, I want the from and to indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chunk the array down into only the first and last indices of every x amount of elements:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
const size = 4

const getIndices = (d, p) => p && p <= Math.ceil(d.length / size) && d.reduce((a, o, i) => {
  const c = Math.floor(i / size);
  a[c] = [].concat((a[c] && a[c][0] || []), o);
  if(a[c].length === 1) a[c] = [a[c][0], a[c][0]]
  return a
}, [])[p - 1].map(i => --i)

for(var i = 1; i < Math.ceil(data.length / size) + 1; i++) {
  console.log(getIndices(data, i))
}
```

EDIT: I just realised this is a simple maths problem. Use this code instead:

```js
var length = 17
const size = 4

const getIndices = (p, s, l) => p && p <= Math.ceil(l / s) && [s * (p - 1), s * p > l - 1 ? l - 1 : s * p - 1]

for(var i = 1; i < Math.ceil(length / size) + 1; i++) {
  console.log(getIndices(i, size, length))
}
```

Second edit:

```js
var length = 17
const size = 4

const getIndices = (p, s, l) => +p && +p <= Math.ceil(l / s) && s * --p

for(var i = 1; i < Math.ceil(length / size) + 1; i++) {
  console.log(getIndices(i, size, length))
}
```

> Note, this function could be a lot shorter, but I have added 2 error checks:
>   `p` checks to see if p actually exists. `&&` chains all of the conditions to make sure all of them are met. `p <= Math.ceil(d.length / size)` checks whether `p` is bigger than the max amount of pages. The next part is the actual logic, returning the page start (and end) indices.

Comment: Thanks much! the output for your console logs should be [0,3],[4,7],and [ 8,11] right ?

Comment: @vrosario fixed now :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! And one last doubt, What if I just happen to pass just the total length of data array and not the data itself. Something like this getIndices(17,1)

Comment: Thank you so much . Guess it breaks for page 5 it is returning [16,17] instead it should be 16 or may be  [16,16] right , Also could you post the previous snippet as well like the one with passing data?

Comment: Whichever you prefer. [16,16] would make more sense here. I've edited to work now 

Comment: Just brilliant! Thanks much:) Also could you post the previous snippet, the one with passing data array?

Comment: Sure, one second.

Comment: @vrosario No worries. If you need more help, feel free to ask :)

Comment: You could just remove it returning the last element and an array. Ill add an edit now